# OpenVPN client pings, but will not resolve DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn

long-time lurker, first time poster. I have read almost every post regarding open-vpn on this site, but I cannot get this issue fixed.

I can connect without issue to openvpn server and can ping internal addresses and 8.8.8.8, but I cannot reach the internet. I have modified the config files for both server and client, iptables, and ensured that my network is configured properly. Server was setup with the road warrior installation. Does anyone who why this will not work? I appreciate the help in advance.

**Server.conf**

```
port 51820
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
```

**client.ovpn**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote [my_public_ip] 51820
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

**IP Tables**

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eno1 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eno1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eno1 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

**Interfaces:**

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.1.213
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

**sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: Have you changed `sysctl.conf`? There should be set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, to enable forwarding.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have included that. I will add above.

Comment: @striker008 how does look routing table on the client when you connect to vpn?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your configuration is okay for TCP connections, but not for UDP and, suddenly, DNS use UDP. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/875728/iptables-redirect-rule-for-udp-not-working) could clarify your problem.

Usually I use `nat` table for NAT organization, instead of using `FORWARD` in `input` table. May be you should try to configure your `iptables` according instruction like [this](https://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial).